# jquery mobile force ui-btn-active on navbar button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with jQuery mobile navigation (navbar).

I have 4 pages and I've set the class="ui-btn-active" to a different one on each page..

For example:

Page 1:

```
<div data-role="footer">
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top" class="ui-btn-active">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="index2.html" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="top">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="index3.html" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
<li><a href="index4.html" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="top">Page 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

then if you go to page 2:

Page 1:

```
<div data-role="footer">
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="index2.html" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="top" class="ui-btn-active">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="index3.html" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
<li><a href="index4.html" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="top">Page 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

etc...

My problem is that it's not always highlighting and sometimes I have to press the button 2 times for it to hightlight.

Does anyone have a clue on how to force this to work?

Comment: For people that want to read the documentation on this feature: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try adding the "ui-state-persist" class to your anchor. 
ex: class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"

Comment: Yeah but, it still breaks occasionally leaving no tabs highlighted or more than one. I guess it's still Beta.

Answer (score 5):

set the link to `href=#` on the active button seemed to fix this for me.

The problem seemed to exist when clicking on the active link although you are already on that page, then navigating away from that page and back to it.

Comment: I was suffering from a similar issue where navigation links would appear as "Active" but the page would never be navigated to.  I found that by replacing my active page href="home.html" to href="#" magically did something and my navigation buttons are responding much better now.  Thanks for the idea.  Hopefully someone else can find this useful.

Comment: I spoke to soon, I'm still having my issues where the button active state appears, but the page is not navigated to.

Comment: Worked for me + `ui-state-persist` on all relevant anchors.

Answer (score 5):

**You have to add the "ui-state-persist" to all the anchor tags**, otherwise it still breaks if you refresh a page, then go to another page, then come back to the page you refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

This only worked for me (in v1.3) if I set class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" on the anchor tags of the ones I wanted to be highlighted (ie, one per page), with the rest of the anchor tags in that navbar with no classes set.