# Jquery button active state

Tags: button, mobile

```
    <body>
    <div data-role="page">

    <div align="center" id="mainPageContent1" data-role="content">    
            <div data-role="controlgroup" id="game_part1s" data-type="horizontal">

<a data-role='button' id='btn1' href='javascript:changeGamePart("Reset1");'>0 - 5 min</a>
<a data-role='button' id='btn2' href='javascript:changeGamePart("2");'>6 - 10 min</a>
<a data-role='button' id='btn3' href='javascript:changeGamePart("3");'>10 - 15 min</a>
<a data-role='button' id='btn4' href='javascript:changeGamePart("4");'>16 - 20 min</a>

             </div>
        </div> 
    </div><!-- /page -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInitialGamePart();
});
function setInitialGamePart() {
    changeGamePart(1);
}
function changeGamePart(nButtonId) {
    for (var iPart = 1; iPart < 5; iPart++) {
        if (nButtonId == iPart) {
    //alert('add class' + iPart);
            $('#btn' + iPart).addClass("ui-btn-active");
            } else {
    //alert('remove class' + iPart);
                $('#btn' + iPart).removeClass("ui-btn-active");
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

On Page Init, the setInitialGamePart is called and it sets the first button as active and rest as not active. When I click any other button, all buttons go not active(normal buttons not highlighted)

Not sure what is the error here

JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fFZ6S/

As you will see, the init works fine but clicking on the button does not. help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the href to href='#' so old code was

```
<a data-role='button' id='btn1' href='javascript:changeGamePart("1");'>0 - 5 min</a>
```

my new code looks like

```
<a data-role='button' id='btn1' href='#' onclick='javascript:changeGamePart("1");'>0 - 5 min</a>
```

Got the hint from this stack..
[jquery mobile force ui-btn-active on navbar button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090922/jquery-mobile-force-ui-btn-active-on-navbar-button)

Here is the JSFiddle for you guys
http://jsfiddle.net/fzaqu/

Hope it helps you